# Class with nested struct as a property doesn't work

Tags: c#, properties, struct

Why doesn't the following code work?
If I change `h` from a property to a field, it works!
Or if I change `FileHeader` from `struct` to a `class` it works!
I am only looking for an answer to why it doesn't work.

```
public class MyFile
{
    public struct FileHeader
    {
        public List<string> ColNames
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void setColNames()
        {
            ColNames = new List<string>();
            ColNames.Add("address");
        }
    }

    public FileHeader h
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyFile o = new MyFile();
        o.h.setColNames();

        Console.WriteLine(o.h.ColNames[0]); // <- Doesn't work! No elements

        string line = System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mutable structs are evil.  Now you know one of the reasons why.

Comment: "...doesn't work"; "... it works!" - that's not really helpful in helping us help you. What do you mean doesn't work? Compile-time error? Runtime error? Improper results? We can guess, because there are some specific characteristics of structs that make it easy to figure out what you're complaining about. But seriously... help us out a bit.

Answer (score 9):

This line:

```
o.h.setColNames();
```

is equivalent to:

```
FileHeader tmp = o.h;
tmp.setColNames();
```

Because `FileHeader` is a struct, the value of `tmp` is a *copy* of the value of the field within `o`. Modifying `tmp` doesn't change `o.h`.

I would suggest:

- You don't create custom structs unless you're creating a natural (small) value type
- Any custom structs you *do* create should be immutable. At that point, it's harder to make this sort of mistake
- Follow .NET naming conventions - a property of `h` and a method of `setColNames` are both violations of this
- Avoid nested types unless there's a significant benefit. It's irrelevant to your actual problem here, but it can make various things trickier.

Comment: +1. Additional suggestion: pay attention to warnings - there should be one on the line that caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Properties are actually methods that are abstracted from you.  It ends up being a Method Called Set.. and a Method called Get... Which retrieves a hidden backing variable or sets a hidden backing variable.

Structs are value types.  When you pass value types to methods it makes copies of them.  E.g. o.h.setColNames is adding to the copy, not the actual instance of o.h's backing field.

If you made a property like

public int SomeInteger { get; set; }

It is also a value type, but it works because the setter is setting the actual instance, and the getter returns you a matching copy.

But with your code, you wrapped your struct with a class, so you always get a copy that setColNames wasn't called on.

This is some dirty code I'm posting here, but it demonstrates how to keep this design and set the new copy by having the struct have a reference to it's parent class.

```
    public class MyFile
{
    public struct FileHeader
    {
        internal MyFile _parent;
        public List<string> ColNames
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void setColNames()
        {
            ColNames = new List<string>();
            ColNames.Add("address");
            _parent._h = this;
        }
    }

    private FileHeader _h = new FileHeader();
    public FileHeader h
    {
        get { return _h; }
    }  

    public MyFile()
    {
        _h._parent = this;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyFile o = new MyFile();
        o.h.setColNames();
        Console.WriteLine(o.h.ColNames[0]);

        string line = System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is horrible, merely a demonstration.  This is a really bad design because it's dumping the old struct onto the GC everytime you call setColNames.